# Confused with type of relationship to be used

Tags: laravel

I have a model 'listing'. And there are 3 types (Business Listing, Franchisor Listing & Franchisee Listing) of the same & each type of listing has different data. Which type of relationship I should go with? How the models will relate? I mean, how the model 'listing' will connect with all the three models? And what will be the structure of 'listing' model, controllers?

Edit: The issue has not yet solved :( As I try to fetch some data from child table via parent, it doesn't give me any result. (Attached an image for better understanding of the structure)[image]

Comment: Could you share your database structure? (preferably an ascii table or a screenshot, its a bit hard to read as human text)

Comment: I haven't yet started making tables/migrations. Just wanted to know the stuff before getting started so as to avoid confusion on the later stage.

Comment: Do business listings, franchisor listings and franchisee listings all have properties that the others don't have? If no, just use a single model with a type (business, franchisor, franchisee).

Comment: All three have different fields.

Comment: Then I'd go the OOP inheritance way. Create a model `Listing` with all the generic properties and methods that you can create on it. Then create the three separate models, each with their own specific properties and methods.

Comment: Can you explain in detail please? As I am a newbie to laravel.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Laravel but with object oriented programming in general. You might wanna follow a couple of courses before attempting stuff like this. Out of experience, it will backfire really quickly if you don't understand the concepts of OOP in a framework that utilizes it.

Comment: Just use the polymorphic relations, you'd have: Listing which contains data about its child (listing_child_id, listing_type) .... ?

Answer (score 1):

I would go for something on the lines of the below:

#### Option 1:

- Listing

  - listing_type_id: [numeric]
  - other_fields_here: [string]
- Listing Types

  - id: [numeric]
  - name: [string]

#### Option 2:

- Generic Listing

  - your_generic_fields_here: [string]
  - child_id: default null [numeric] -> points to a type (franchise, business etc)

*The above can also be done the other way around; the child links to the parent rather than the parent to the child. Just add parent_id in the listings below.*

- Franchise Listing

  - other_fields_here: [string]
- Business Listing

  - other_fields_here: [string]
- Other Listing types....

Identify which columns you need, and which are shared between the listing types, and put them in the generic listing table; create other tables for the rest and use a parent_id for the generic data; or just totally use different tables.

#### Laravel

I wouldn't over complicate this, just use three models that derive from the Listing base model; the base model can hold which listing type and other data as shown [here](https://adamwathan.me/2015/09/03/pushing-polymorphism-to-the-database/).

You can read more about polymorphic relations [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations).